# Sticky header does not stick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I read many topics but I can't solve this. In js fiddle it works..in my browser it does not.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stFcx/2766/)

and this is a screen of my browser..the green header won't stick to the top but some lines below..

[image: screenshot]

this is the code in my page

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" title="Style" media="all" />
    <title> title </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sticky-header.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $("table").stickyTableHeaders();
      });
    </script>
<table.... //from here is identical to the fiddle html
```

thanks

Comment: Which browser are you using?  It seems to kind of work in chrome...

You may want to consider a grid alternative, such as jqgrid (there are many others)

Comment: Did you check the browser console? Did you see some error there? Are you sure that both libraries are correctly loaded?

Comment: never used the browser console (I'm on firefox) but in console->errors it's empty..libraries are fine..I'm trying to understand if there might be some conflict with other css or html stuff..

Comment: Please reply on weather your problem was fixed or not xD Thank You lol

Answer (score 1):

The following line of code seems to be a piece of optimization that is causing problems. The line below it tells the header where to position itself, but this part is telling the function to exit early because it thinks it's not necessary for some reason. Taking it out means that the code may run a bit slower, but will always work. It seems to run fine without it but if the page is noticeably lagging when scrolling in a real-world scenario then it might be better to try optimizing it instead of just taking it out completely.

```
if (!base.isSticky || winScrollTop < 0 || winScrollTop + base.$window.height() <= base.$originalHeader.parent().get(0).scrollHeight || winScrollLeft < 0 || winScrollLeft + base.$window.width() > base.$document.width()) {
    return;
}
```

For some reason this works fine in jsfiddle where there are different frames, but does not work when everything is in the main window. **Easy solution: remove it**.

Answer (score -1):

For the header just make it `position: fixed`. That will make it stick to the top! :)

**EDIT**
This does not require Javascript (JQuery). This can be simply done with CSS. Make a ID for the header container, and then make it position:fixed. Simple! Then it will stick to the top of the page.

**EDIT 2**

Please refer to this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/yu765bwh/
**IMPORTANT** I have meant position:fixed not relative!

Comment: you mean like this? `.table thead{
 position: relative;
 }` this is not working

Comment: Let me post a example.

Comment: ok..I found out what's wrong (but not solved)..I updated your fiddle..as I add some stuff before the head, it won't stik to the top..in fact it is sticked to its own position, not to the top..my original table does not begin at the top of the page (there's a menu, some text and other things above).http://jsfiddle.net/yu765bwh/2/

Comment: @Ska Frez, Ok first off why would you put stuff above your header? But if you do put stuff above your header add this: http://jsfiddle.net/yu765bwh/3/. It is basically just adding 0px from the top. But I heavily suggest not putting stuff before the header.

Comment: @michaeljones, that latest fiddle moves the header to the top. I think OP wants to only have it sticky after scrolling to where it is at the top. There are a myriad of reasons why there might be something above the table header.

Comment: @redbmk, Oh, I think he wanted it to stick to the top of the page.

Comment: ok..maybe I wasn't clear..I have a normal php page..In this page I have other things (like the menu) that are above the table..and looks quite normal to me..my table is in the middle of my page..the first row of the table (the table header) is the one that should stick on top of the page, when scrolling down.. lokk this screen is my page..there's the black menu, some space, text, image and then begin the table.. http://www16.zippyshare.com/v/niHylCfz/file.html

Comment: Oh ok now that makes more sense! :) Use "Position:Relative" and "Margin-top:0px" on the table header. Will that work?

Comment: UGH sorry, position:fixed. For some odd reason I have relative in my head xD It SHOULD be position:fixed.

Comment: mm nothing..still not attached to the top..ok I am pretty sure this mess is caused by some other part of my code..I updated the fiddle (I added the menu I am using right now) and it works..then I'll try everything one by one and see what's causing this issue.. http://jsfiddle.net/stFcx/2767/

Comment: I will try to find the problem aswell! :)

Comment: Yes! Only problem it is a tiny bit from the top afterwards, maybe margin-top:0px?

Comment: crap..for me it doesn't stick..when scrolling down there a space (almost equivalent to 1 row of the table) between the top and the header row EDIT: can't believe..it's working in IE..then the problem is firefox?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75243/discussion-between-michael-jones-and-ska-frenz).

Comment: @SkaFrenz, The example at assatena.it shows the issue for me in Chrome, but I'm not seeing it in the jsfiddle

Comment: I'm not using chrome but I see it working too in jsfiddle..also working in IE..not working in firefox..